# How to set custom LODs in ArcGIS iOS

Tags: ios, arcgis

I need to zoom to an extent smaller than the minimum LOD of the tiled basemap layer. 
In the ArcGIS Javascript API it's possible to add LODs to the map object, so the tiled layer simply stops drawing at larger scales, but I can't find the equivalent in the iOS SDK.

My backup plan is to detect the change of extent and turn off the layer myself, but I'm specifically interested in finding out if/how I can set the LODs directly.

thanks.

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: This would be better off on GIS-SE
https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_l_o_d.html